# SO doesn't account for GMT/BST changes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, timezone

I couldn't find any dupes for this and it isn't a big blocker, but I thought it worth noting.

We move from GMT to [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time) (British Summer Time = GMT+1) during the summer months in the UK, but SO doesn't reflect this in interface, so with regard to voting/review limits, they reset at 01:00 instead of 00:00 and thus the notion of "today" for UK users is skewed by an hour for six months:

At 00:08 this morning, I get:

[image]

Comment: This is by-design. SO is UTC, always.

Comment: It's always skewed for most of the world. Here it resets at 4 or 5 in the afternoon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the rest of the world's experience.

Stack Overflow "accounts" for the GMT/BST difference by ignoring it and only using GMT.

For me a Stack Overflow day begins in the late afternoon/early evening.

Comment: Yess, that's fair enough. Thanks.